# Error filtering 2 files using AWK for a given condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk

First of all, thank you for your help. I have a problem filtering 2 files using AWK conditionals. The two files I want to filter are these one: Fasta.fa

```
>SiiA   lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463122.1_4111   100.000 100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDDSNPNEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTYKIKAWLEDKINSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
>SiiA   lcl|NC_010102.1_prot_WP_000389232.1_4169    99.048  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDDSNPNEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIKAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
>SiiA   lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV25805.1_4154 97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIESKTKSTAQNSGANDNSNANEIINKEVNTQDMSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIKAWLEDKINSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
>SiiA   lcl|NZ_CP009559.1_prot_WP_000389229.1_1106  97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNNGANDNSNANEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIEAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
>SiiA   lcl|NZ_CP029897.1_prot_WP_000389235.1_4284  97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDNSNANEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKIDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIEAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
>SiiA   lcl|NZ_CP053416.1_prot_WP_079774927.1_2027  77.619  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMLIMYDNSIKVYKTNIEKHANSKDEKSGDNKKENTNEKVENETISKDSSAESTEMSGKEIGIYDIADDQRIDITSEEKELVITYRGRLRSFSKEDLNKITVWLEDKANSNLLIEMIIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSTASSSTSKAIITTTNKKVPE
```

species_id (the file is larger and contain the name of different species)

```
**Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis** >lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV21904.1_1
**Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis** >lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV21905.1_2
**Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis** >lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV21906.1_3
**Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis** >lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV21907.1_4
**Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis** >lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV21908.1_5
**Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis** >lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV26199.1_6
**Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis** >lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV21909.1_7
```

I want to use awk so it puts in fasta.fa the name of the species if both $2 in both files are the same in  so the output in a new file will be something similar as this:

```
SiiA    **Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhimurium_LT2**  lcl|NC_003197.2_prot_NP_463122.1_4111   100.000 100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDDSNPNEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTYKIKAWLEDKINSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiA    **Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Paratyphi_B**  lcl|NC_010102.1_prot_WP_000389232.1_4169    99.048  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDDSNPNEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIKAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiA    **Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Infantis** lcl|CP052796.1_prot_QJV25805.1_4154 97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIESKTKSTAQNSGANDNSNANEIINKEVNTQDMSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIKAWLEDKINSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiA    **Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Paratyphi_A**  lcl|NZ_CP009559.1_prot_WP_000389229.1_1106  97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNNGANDNSNANEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKTDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIEAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiA    **Salmonella_enterica_subsp_enterica_Typhi**    lcl|NZ_CP029897.1_prot_WP_000389235.1_4284  97.143  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMIIMYDNSIKVYKANIENKTKSTAQNSGANDNSNANEIVNKEVNTQDVSDGMTTMSGKEVGVYDIADGQKIDITSTKNELVITYHGRLRSFSEEDTHKIEAWLEDKTNSNLLIEMVIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSAASSTTSKAIITTINKKVSE
SiiA    **Salmonella_bongori**  lcl|NZ_CP053416.1_prot_WP_079774927.1_2027  77.619  100 MEDESNPWPSFVDTFSTVLCIFIFLMLVFALNNMLIMYDNSIKVYKTNIEKHANSKDEKSGDNKKENTNEKVENETISKDSSAESTEMSGKEIGIYDIADDQRIDITSEEKELVITYRGRLRSFSKEDLNKITVWLEDKANSNLLIEMIIPQADISFSDSLRLGYERGIILMKEIKKIYPDVVIDMSVNSTASSSTSKAIITTTNKKVPE
```

The "**" are not in the file I just put them to show all of you what I am doing. I have tried this two codes but none of them give the result I expect

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next}{$2=a[FNR]}1' species_id fasta.fa >> final
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next} $1 in a {$3=$4;$2=$3;$2=a[$1];$4=$5;$5=$6}1' species_id fasta.fa >> final
```

Comment: `awk` reads input files one by one and not side by side. Another thing, field `$2` is different in both files, take a look at the output of `awk '{print $2}' species_id fasta.fa`. Which part of `$2` should match?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work if your data is proper. 2nd column in file1 and file2 should match, which isn't currently with the sample posted.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$0; next} ($2 in a){print a[$2]" "$0}' file1 file2
```